# Cannot connect to Mongdb in azure cosmosdb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am new in connecting to Node + Mongodb app in Azure CosmosDb.I followed this step https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-mongodb-nodejs for demo purpose to my cosmos account.

Now when I have updated my package I got an error of 
`Could not connect to MongoDB!
Error: Password contains an illegal unescaped character`

Where should I make changes to make this things work ?
Currently local-development js file contains this structure.

```
module.exports = {
  db: {
    uri: 'mongodb://<cosmosdb-name>:LNpm5RUk3fxJGMlA1xe0cZzcPVUDf2uLz70e0wRwhKoI05REN0V5560jbpLI00V9XlwbRZyMePsEPtSMtyw==@<cosmosdb-name>.documents.azure.com:10255/mean-dev?ssl=true&sslverifycertificate=false'
  }
};
```

This is the first  time I am touching microsoft framework. Need a guidance right here.

Comment: can you add you connection code?

Comment: @AZ_  There are so many files in this cloned project. I am not sure how the connection has been done.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates character `==` in your connect string.

From the solution in this [link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6044),you could use `encodeURIComponent()` function to encode your password if you have any characters that are reserved according to the [IETF URI spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2).

---

Just for summary,fianlly,reconfiguring Mongodb and no need to encode url resolved the issue.

Comment: But that is the cosmos key I am getting . Let me encode it

Comment: @NoobCoder Any luck?

Comment: Yes I got it . I do not need to encode as I reconfigured Mongodb and its working fine now, Thanks

Comment: @NoobCoder Cheers, i tried to summarized your solution in the answer,if you do not mind ,you could mark it for others' reference on the forum,Thanks you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your db url when you password contains special cahracters.

```
module.exports = {
  db: {
    uri: encodeURI('mongodb://<cosmosdb-name>:LNpm5RUk3fxJGMlA1xe0cZzcPVUDf2uLz70e0wRwhKoI05REN0V5560jbpLI00V9XlwbRZyMePsEPtSMtyw==@<cosmosdb-name>.documents.azure.com:10255/mean-dev?ssl=true&sslverifycertificate=false')
  }
};
```

Comment: I am getting `Could not connect to MongoDB!
Error: Password contains an illegal unescaped character` after adding encodeURI